# Which eslint plugin catches key errors in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint

I am using eslint in nextjs and When running a loop using MAP, no errors are thrown even though I didn't put a value for KEY.
What settings do I need to install to be notified of errors?

Below is my eslint configuration.

```
{
  "extends": [
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "plugins": ["simple-import-sort"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "simple-import-sort/imports": "error",
    "simple-import-sort/exports": "error",
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": [
      2,
      {
        "some": ["nesting", "id"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Also, can't I just give an index to a key value in a regular array (where the order doesn't change)? What should I do when there are no other values available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React's key requirement rule is `react/jsx-key` which is a part of `eslint-plugin-react`. You can check it out in [this document](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-key.md).

To install it, you can follow these steps:

1. Install the package

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-react
Or
yarn add --dev eslint-plugin-react
```

2. Put `"plugin:react/recommended"` under `eslintrc` config file

```
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "plugins": ["simple-import-sort"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "simple-import-sort/imports": "error",
    "simple-import-sort/exports": "error",
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": [
      2,
      {
        "some": ["nesting", "id"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that the order of `extends` items matters, so you can arrange that list based on your own preferred rules.

Comment: I put it at the top and it didn't change, but I put it at the bottom and it works fine, thanks!